# what is the issue with User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, authentication, namespaces

What namespace is it from, cause it shows me that User doesnt exist in the current context!

Here are my list of namespaces. Which one should i add:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
```

Another question, is that the way to check that the person who logged in is an administrator?

```
 if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "Administrators"))
      {
```

Comment: Is this code in a Page or a class library? In a class library the User should be in HttpContext.Current

Comment: The code is inside a simple class.. where should i put HttpContext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the following namespace:

```
using System.Security.Principal;
```

The easiest way to check for roles is:

```
User.IsInRole("Administractor");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are in a code library rather than the web page itself you need:

```
HttpContext.Current.User
```